# Unobtrusive client-side validation for bool field not working in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

**I found a very interesting problem in ASP.NET Core.** I am using my bool field for a checkbox. I want to force the user to check the checkbox for the form to be submitted.

This bool field in my Model class is:

```
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You must accept the Terms")]
public bool TermsAccepted { get; set; }
```

Notice I have applied [Range] validation attribute. And it works **perfectly** for the **Server side validation**.

My action method code is fairly simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(JobApplication jobApplication)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Accepted", jobApplication);
    else
        return View();
}
```

> ***But the problem is happening when I apply client side validation***

On my view i apply the 3 scripts:

```
@section scripts {
<script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js">
</script>
}
```

The client side validation works totally opposite, it is giving error message when I check the checkbox. Why it is happening opposite?

The HTML code produced by the checkbox is:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-range="You must accept the Terms" data-val-range-max="True" data-val-range-min="True" data-val-required="The TermsAccepted field is required." id="TermsAccepted" name="TermsAccepted" value="true" aria-describedby="TermsAccepted-error">
```

Please help?

Comment: Your input has `value="true"`, (lower case) but validation range attribute values are `"True"` (upper case `T`), so it does not match

Comment: What you should be doing as creating a custom `ValidationAttribute` (say `[MustBeTrue]`) and adding the rules to the `$.validator`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok i understand but on the [Range] attribute I gave them 'true' and not 'True', then why is it happening? Also I do not want to create custom validator because the my range validation is working correctly on server side but on client side it is working totally opposite. I think it is a bug in asp.net core mvc.

Comment: Not sure. Using `"true"` in the `RangeAttribute` (i.e. a `string`) should generate `data-val-range-max="true"`

Comment: Just noticed you have `typeof(bool)` - change that to `typeof(string)` and it should generate the correct html

Comment: However, that will still not solve your issue because the input always has a value of `"true"`, so you would need to write a script to override the range rule for checkboxes

Comment: ok got it. I will have to write my own jQuery script for overriding this rule. I think Microsoft should correct this bug.

Comment: Its not a bug! - and `jquery.validate.js` is not even a Microsoft product.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, your code is ok with a few additions...

I updated to the latest versions of jquery.validate (1.19.1) and jquery.validation.unobtrusive (3.2.11), (using libman to manage these dependencies).

Also I added this javascript block to extend the functionality of the validator methods on that page.

```js
 <script>
      // extend range validator method to treat checkboxes differently
      var defaultRangeValidator = $.validator.methods.range;
      $.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
        if(element.type === 'checkbox') {
          // if it's a checkbox return true if it is checked
          return element.checked;
        } else {
          // otherwise run the default validation function
          return defaultRangeValidator.call(this, value, element, param);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### All about jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Maybe too late. But I found one solution for validating check box 'Must Be True'. **It will work on client side and server side as well**.

It's possible to use same as with ConfirmPassword, but need to include to model one more hidden property bool with 'true' value. And to compare your check box with this property. Or just to use pure HTML if you have api call.

##### HTML for direct use

```
<div class="input-group has-validation">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="You have to agree with 'Terms amd Conditions' to register" data-val-equalto-other="AgreedWithTerms" data-val-required="You have to agree with 'Terms amd Conditions' to register" id="AgreeWithTerms" name="AgreeWithTerms" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="AgreedWithTerms" type="hidden" value="true">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AgreeWithTerms" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="AgreeWithTerms">
            <strong>Agree with</strong>
            <a class="" href="/terms/" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions...</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case of ASP.NET Core or Framework. Just include one hidden bool property to model "AgreedWithTerms" with value 'true' as follows:

##### C# Model

```
 [Required]
 [Compare("AgreedWithTerms", ErrorMessage = "You have to agree with 'Terms amd Conditions' to register")]
 public bool AgreeWithTerms { get; set; }

 [HiddenInput]
 public bool AgreedWithTerms { get; set; } = true;
```